# Is it possible to use Oracle Label Security in Entity Framework Data Context?

Tags: oracle, entity-framework

I have a table configured with an OLS policy (levels, compartments, groups) - a user with a specific OLS user label can only access some rows in the table according to their OLS data label. Right now, I'm using strings to connect to the Oracle Database then make a query from that table (like "select * from mytable"). May I ask is it possible to use Entity Context for that? Like one data context but multiple user Oracle account (schemas) with different user labels query from that single Entity context so that I don't have to use strings?

Answer (score 0):

Label security (OLS) affects the rows shown to a user - not colums etc.

i.e. the data model is for any user allowed to select the tables the same - so if you got User1 granted to select table T1 but OLS restricted access for User1 to data connected to asian location, User1 will see only asian data but not rows for european locations - If User2 is a "superuser" - i.e. allowed to fetch rows from any location, User2 will see any rows.

The simpliest way to prove this is to do

desc T1

Both users will see same table description - and thats what EF / LINQ relates on. So - as User with OLS and granted select table you got 0, subset or all rows - but Everytime table description

Comment: Ex: Right now I have an user "admin" and table "company" configured with an OLS policy. When I create the Entity context based on schema "admin"."company", any query I make is base on this schema only. I want to change the context's connection to others schema like: manager, employee1,...
I have tried [link](https://entityframework.net/change-connection-at-runtime) but it's not working.

Comment: Please see  https://medium.com/@pawel.gerr/entity-framework-core-changing-database-schema-at-runtime-dcf1211768c6